# How to change DBLookupComboBox value in Delphi?

Tags: database, delphi, combobox

I'm trying to change the visible text (value) of a DBLookupComboBox, using :

```
DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue:=S;
```

and

```
DBLookupComboBox2.KeyValue:=X;
```

If the KeyValue and S are strings, then everything works fine, and I can set the value.

But when the KeyValue is an integer/Int64 (UID in the DB), and X is an Int64 variable - it doesn't work, and nothing changes.

So for an example, i need to set "Amsterdam" in DBLookupComboBox1, and 1500 in DBLookupComboBox2.
"Amsterdam" from the "City" field of the users, and 1500 as the UID.

What am I doing wrong please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is Important for you:

```
lkcbbArzSource.KeyValue:=2;//c(or another number);
```

`lkcbbArzSource` is a `dbLookupComboBox` object and you can insert only a number in this!why? because is numeric and another side of that there is a field that show a text or String of that numeric in combo.

in below sample code you can see a `dbLookupComboBox` how to menage and fill with Data-set and add in a grid :

```
rzSource.Enabled:= True;
lkcbbArzSource.Font.Size:=8;
lkcbbArzSource.Tag := V_Counter;
lkcbbArzSource.Visible:= True;
lkcbbArzSource.Enabled:= True;
lkcbbArzSource.Font.Name:='tahoma';
lkcbbArzSource.ListSource := myDsrSource;
lkcbbArzSource.KeyField := 'Code';
lkcbbArzSource.ListField := 'Des';
lkcbbArzSource.KeyValue:=  IntToStr(FieldByName('P_ARZSOURCE').AsInteger);
lkcbbArzSource.OnChange := myBicLookUpChange;
SGrid2.Objects[look_col,lkcbbArzSource.Tag]:= lkcbbArzSource;
SGRID2.Objects[look_col,V_Counter] := nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the KeyValue calls the SetKeyValue of the TDBLookupControl which in Delphi 7 appears as:

```
procedure TDBLookupControl.SetKeyValue(const Value: Variant);
begin
  if not VarEquals(FKeyValue, Value) then
  begin
    FKeyValue := Value;
    KeyValueChanged;
  end;
end;

procedure TDBLookupComboBox.KeyValueChanged;
begin
  if FLookupMode then
  begin
    FText := FDataField.DisplayText;
    FAlignment := FDataField.Alignment;
  end else
  if ListActive and LocateKey then
  begin
    FText := FListField.DisplayText;
    FAlignment := FListField.Alignment;
  end else
  begin
    FText := '';
    FAlignment := taLeftJustify;
  end;
  Invalidate;
end;
```

As you can see, your variable x is used as part of a LocateKey.

```
function TDBLookupControl.LocateKey: Boolean;
var
  KeySave: Variant;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    KeySave := FKeyValue;
    if not VarIsNull(FKeyValue) and FListLink.DataSet.Active and
      FListLink.DataSet.Locate(FKeyFieldName, FKeyValue, []) then // << ---here
    begin
      Result := True;
      FKeyValue := KeySave;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Stepping into these procedures and functions should help you to debug your issue.  All are located in the DbCtrls unit..

Comment: ty John. there is no conversion. in the string combo(let's say DBLookupComboBox1) i use names, and in the integer combo(let's say DBLookupComboBox2), i use only the ID numbers).
so in DBLookupComboBox1 i want it to be for example : Amsterdam
and in DBLookupComboBox2 i want it to be for example : 1500.
i will edit my question

Comment: I shouldn't have said string conversion, edit answer and removed that reference.  Set a break point and compare the two values (compare X as a variant and the underlying lookup database field value as a variant).  As another test, compare them both as strings.

Comment: the thing is that when i debug, i can see the the number i need DOES get into the Keyvalue, but it just doesn't show it on the screen...

Comment: Edited again, hope this helps.  You need to step into these functions and evaluate your variables.

Comment: sorry for my broken english...
as a simple explanation : everything works fine, but just doesn't show it on screen if the keyvalue that i change is an Integer  :)

Comment: I think it's not changing because the integer value is not located within the lookup dataset.  If a string works, why not just use DBLookupComboBox2.KeyValue := inttostr(X) ?

Comment: IntToStr is a really good idea, and i see it gets the info correctly, but i still see everything fine in Debug, but not on the screen.
maybe it compares the number to the actual data type (Variant<->BigInt) ?

Comment: Usually the KeyValue is not displayed in the text field of the DBLookupComboBox. The visible field is taken from the property ListField. To show the KeyValue you have to set the ListField property to the same field name as the KeyField property.

Comment: thank you Uwe and sorry for not clearing this. my ListField is "City" (string), and the KeyField is UID (Int64/BigInt).  i want the DBLookupComboBox to show the City according to the UID that i want to set.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this and solved my problem.

Use this lines of code at `Form1.OnShow`  :

```
DBLookupComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Locate('City', 'Amsterdam', []);
DBLookupComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.FieldByName(DBLookupComboBox1.KeyField).Value;


DBLookupComboBox2.ListSource.DataSet.Locate('UID', '1500', []);
DBLookupComboBox2.ListSource.DataSet.FieldByName(DBLookupComboBox2.KeyField).Value;
```